# identifying difference in non identical dataframe having common columns based on linking through a key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['123','456','789'], 'B': ['D1','D4','D7'], 'C':['D2','D5','D8'], 'D':['D3','D6','D9']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'A': ['123','789','111','222'], 'B': ['D1','D7','D11','D14'], 'C':['D10','D8','D12','D15'], 'D':['D3','D9','D13','16']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

The primary key link between the 2 frames is column 'A'.

Output desired -

1. df1 - rows which are not present in df2 ('A' = 456)
2. df2 - rows which are not present in df1 ('A' = 111 and 'A' = 222)
3. common rows with differences - ('A' = 123 - column 'C' = D2 vs D10

Comment: what have you already tried? Please, share your functional code

Comment: i tried this - res = (pd.concat([df1,df2])
       .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
       .drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='last')
      )

Comment: also: what does `'A' = 123 - column 'C' = D2 vs D10` mean?

Comment: in column with 'A' as 123 there is difference in column 'C' between the two data sets. df1 has D2 and df2 has D10 - hence that difference needed in output. For rows with no such difference - they need to be ignored.

Comment: what if there are multiple rows in `df1` and/or `df2` that share a certain value of `A`? What should the result of (3) look like then?

Comment: A will be unique in each frame - that isnt possible @PierreD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** df1 - rows which are not present in df2:

```
q1=df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]

'''
     A   B   C   D
1  456  D4  D5  D6
'''
```

**Q2:** df2 - rows which are not present in df1:

```
q2=df2[~df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])]

'''
     A    B    C    D
2  111  D11  D12  D13
3  222  D14  D15   16
'''
```

**Q3:** Common rows with differences:

```
q3=pd.concat([df1[df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])],df2[df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])]]).drop_duplicates().groupby('A').agg(list)
mask=q3.applymap(lambda x: pd.Series(x).is_unique if len(x) > 1 else False)
q3=q3[mask].stack().reset_index()

'''
     A    level_1          0
0  123       C        [D2, D10]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar to @Bushmaster's answer for the first two questions. But a slightly different approach to show the differences among the rows where `A` is common.

```py
df1x2 = df1.loc[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]
df2x1 = df2.loc[~df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])]
dfcom = df1.merge(df2, on='A', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
```

Then, to highlight the differences within each row of `dfcom`:

```py
def show_diffs(s):
    a = {k[:-2]: v for k, v in s.items() if k.endswith('_1')}
    b = {k[:-2]: v for k, v in s.items() if k.endswith('_2')}
    return {k: (a[k], b[k]) for k in a if a[k] != b[k]}

>>> dfcom.assign(diffs=dfcom.apply(show_diffs, axis=1))
     A B_1 C_1 D_1 B_2  C_2 D_2                 diffs
0  123  D1  D2  D3  D1  D10  D3  {'C': ('D2', 'D10')}
1  789  D7  D8  D9  D7   D8  D9                    {}

# or, just the differences
>>> dfcom[['A']].assign(diffs=dfcom.apply(show_diffs, axis=1))
     A                 diffs
0  123  {'C': ('D2', 'D10')}
1  789                    {}
```

Another possibility, if the common `dfcom` is not too large, is to present the differences visually:

```py
def highlight(df):
    cols_1 = [k for k in df.columns if k.endswith('_1')]
    cols_2 = [k for k in df.columns if k.endswith('_2')]
    a = df[cols_1].set_axis([k[:-2] for k in cols_1], axis=1)
    b = df[cols_2].set_axis([k[:-2] for k in cols_2], axis=1)
    h = pd.concat([
        # just in case the columns are somehow in a different order
        (a != b[a.columns]).set_axis(cols_1, axis=1),
        (b != a[b.columns]).set_axis(cols_2, axis=1),
    ], axis=1).applymap(
        lambda v: 'color:red; font-weight:bold' if v else 'color:lightblue')
    return h

dfcom.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what you've asked by:

- changing the index to `A`
- pre-calculating subsets of common and distinct values of `A`
- reading off the appropriate rows by index (i.e., by value of `A`) for non-common rows in `df1` and `df2`
- creating a mask for common rows flagging non-matching values and using this to construct `V1 vs V2` style strings in positions that have differing values, with like values marked with NaN.

```py
# pre-calculation of partitioning of `A` values, to avoid duplicate operations
a1, a2 = df1.set_index('A'), df2.set_index('A')
s1, s2 = set(a1.index), set(a2.index)
sCommon = s1 & s2
lCommon = list(sCommon)

# calculation of outputs (rows only in df1, rows only in df2, and common rows)
out1, out2 = a1.loc[list(s1 - sCommon),], a2.loc[list(s2 - sCommon),]
mask = a1.loc[lCommon,] != a2.loc[lCommon,]
out3 = (a1.loc[lCommon,].astype(str)[mask] + ' vs ' + a2.loc[lCommon,].astype(str)[mask])
```

Output:

```
out1
      B   C   D
A
456  D4  D5  D6

out2
       B    C    D
A
222  D14  D15   16
111  D11  D12  D13

out3
       B          C    D
A
123  NaN  D2 vs D10  NaN
789  NaN        NaN  NaN
```